# How can I copy an LVM configuration to another machine?

Tags: linux, lvm, lvm2

I inherited a machine that's set up with 3 disks, managed by LVM (v 2.02.46-RHEL5). I just got a new box with the same hardware configuration, and would like to clone the disk setup by copying an LVM config file from the first box to the second, and have LVM on the new box set up the disks according to that same configuration. Is there a way to do this? I'm new to LVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the already installed system, under the /root folder you should find a file named anaconda-ks.cfg.
You can use this file for replicate a previous installation to another one.

Take a look [here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone all the data (including OS):

1. Create LVM volumes on new box
2. dd LVs out to image files on old box (you may need to do this in a OS other the one on disk, such as Live system like http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora )
3. copy images to new box
4. dd images to LVs on new box (also in a separate OS)
5. Boot the system.

I duplicate LVM volume across machines frequently to clone Xen VMs. You may refer to [here](http://fclose.com/b/2611/) for some details.

Comment: That's helpful for future reference, but what I'd like to do is just copy the disk partition setup, not the actual data. In particular, I'd like a process that doesn't involve creating the LVM volumes first, if possible.